# Colorfull netcat chat

Tags: bash, netcat

**TLDR;** Server side `nc -l PORT` such that all clients see server messages in a particular color.

I am able to print red text: `echo -e "\e[31mRed Message"`
I am able to pipe that text to netcat: `echo -e "\e[31mRed Message" | nc -l 1234`. This allows a user who connects to me to see a red message (if their terminal supports colors).
But I am unaware of how to send all of my messages in a given netcat chat session in a particular color

The trouble with `echo -e "\e[31mRed Message" | nc -l 1234` is that only one message gets printed in red and then the server (the machine listening on port 1234) cannot send messages anymore. I am looking for a way to constantly redirect `stdin` and process it differently (color it) before sending it as an outgoing message over netcat.

Normally netcat chatting might look like this:
Server: `nc -l 1234`
Client: `nc ${SERVER_IP} 1234`

> Hello I am the server
>   Hello I am a client
>   I am the server and my messages are boring and not colored
>   I am a client and my messages are equally boring

What I would like to ideally do is this
Server: `some magic netcat thing that colors server text`
Client: `nc ${SERVER_IP} 1234`

> **Hello I am the server**
>   Hello I am a client
>   **I am the server and my messages are cool and are all colored red!**
>   I am a client and I can see your cool red colored messages, my messages are boring though :(

*bold text used in above example to represent red text*

[Good reference for bash coloring codes](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Comment: So is this color thing relevant to netcat in any way? If you want to print your text colored in a particular way, then your _terminal_ needs to support showing them in color and you communicate that to your terminal using [ascii escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: Well `\e[31m` set's all the following colors to red. So just send it first. What do you mean by "__all__"? What messages exactly?

Comment: What about adding `\e[31m` at the beginning of each line and adding the reset color ansi escape code at the end of each line, where the line is send from the server to the client. Like `sed 's/^/\x1b\[31m/g; s/$/\x1b<the reset code>/g' | netcat ...`

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do, but the issue is with taking text from ```stdin```, coloring it, then sending it to the netcat process. The method you describe with ```sed``` causes ```stdin``` to never make it to ```netcat```

Comment: I guess because of line buffering in the pipe. Try adding `stdbuf -oL sed ....`. Or `sed -u` I think

Comment: That is super close!!! Wow! Cool! It is only showing up on the client side in red though. For some reason on the server side it still shows up as uncolored...

Comment: Well, you would need to output the red ansi code before you type anything. That would require a lot of synchronization between client and server. It will get complicated. So if you really want that, I suggest write a C program that controls the terminal device (ncurses) and implement it all yourself.

Comment: You helped me get there, but I ended up not needing to write a C program. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210442/discussion-between-lenna-and-kamilcuk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full Solution, based upon [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)  comments

Server:

```
NO_COLOR="\x1b\[0m"      # Uncolored
SERVER_COLOR="\x1b\[31m" # Red

sed -u "s/^/${SERVER_COLOR}/g; s/$/${NO_COLOR}/g" | nc -l 1234 | sed "s/^/${NO_COLOR}/g; s/$/${SERVER_COLOR}/g"
```

Client: `nc ${SERVER_IP} 1234`

> **I am server.**
>   I am client.
>   **I see that I am red and you are uncolored.**
>   I see that you are red. And I see that I am uncolored!
>   **We see the same thing!**

Server:

```
NO_COLOR="\x1b\[0m"      # Uncolored
SERVER_COLOR="\x1b\[31m" # Red
CLIENT_COLOR="\x1b\[32m" # Green

sed -u "s/^/${SERVER_COLOR}/g; s/$/${NO_COLOR}/g" | nc -l 1234 | sed "s/^/${CLIENT_COLOR}/g; s/$/${SERVER_COLOR}/g"
```

Client: `nc ${SERVER_IP} 1234`

> **I am server**
>   *I am client*
>   **I see that I am red and you are green**
>   *I see that you are red, but I appear to be uncolored to myself*
>   **We see similar but different things**

Tricks to make this work:

1. The input to the `netcat` process is now the output from a `sed -u` process. The `sed -u` process is what gets `stdin`.
2. The output from the `netcat` process is now the input to a `sed` process. This `sed` process is what generates `stdout`.
3. Both `sed` scripts make use of `^` to *prepend* a color code to the **beginning** of a line and `$` to *append* a color code to the **end** of a line.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me if I use it on the server side:

```
#!/bin/bash

red="$(tput setaf 1)"
off="$(tput sgr0)"

while read line ; do
   printf "${red}${line}${off}\n"
done | nc -l 1234
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is good. It achieves the goal of coloring the text, but it does not color the server text on both sides. I was hoping all server messages would appear in red (for all participants)?

Comment: I did that because your question says... *"such that all clients see server messages in a particular color."* :-)